# invalid END header (bad central directory offset) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

When I try to build cucumber-report from GitHub https://github.com/mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports using eclipse maven install, I am getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.10
>   (C:\maven2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-checkstyle-plugin\2.10\maven-checkstyle-plugin-2.10.jar):
>   **invalid END header (bad central directory offset) -> [Help 1] [ERROR]**
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full
>   debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors
>   and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR]
>   [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescriptorParsingException

Comment: I don't know if there is enough information there to help you. Did you get the full stack trace as it suggested?

Comment: Here is a [possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366254/invalid-end-header-bad-central-directory-size-zipexception).

Comment: i am trying to generate testing report for cucumber automation ,so i found some github project from  https://github.com/mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports ,when i try to build this application i am getting this error.

Comment: Delete the file `C:\maven2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-checkstyle-plugin\2.10\maven-checkstyle-plugin-2.10.jar` and try it again. As already posted it might be related to the corrupted file.