# Eclipse installation failed with an error

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to install Eclipse with the Eclipse Installer. At the End of the installation i get the message `"Installation failed with an error. See the log."` My PC is `64-Bit` and my `jdk` and the installer too, so its not the problem.
Could you please have a look at my `log`, i don't understand the issue.

---

Thats the log:

```
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 9.0.4+11
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.oxygen
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.9.0.v20171202-1121, build=3282, branch=f99b41819cc9f86beec6b54bf453173fc2d4acef
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Oxygen))
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Offline = false
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Mirrors = true
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Resolving 25 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\java-oxygen\eclipse
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement epp.package.java [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.7.0,4.8.0)
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.news.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000
[2018-05-05 10:12:59] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2018-05-05 10:13:18] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2018-05-05 10:13:25] Computing prerequisite plan
[2018-05-05 10:13:34] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/oxygen in 0.469s
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2018-05-05 10:13:35] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/201804111000 in 0.645s
[2018-05-05 10:13:44] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2018-05-05 10:13:44] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3324)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3252)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3133)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__java-oxygen_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Konrad\.p2\pool\plugins\org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:317)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3324)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3252)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3133)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1111)
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3324)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3252)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3133)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1298)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1166)
    ... 1 more
```

---

Thak you for your help!

Comment: I would suggest that you have the latest version of both JRE and JDK installed in 32 and 64-bit architecture. And then try running the Eclipse installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important parts of the exception you posted are :

```
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__java-oxygen_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Konrad\.p2\pool\plugins\org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found
```

We can see the the installation attempted to read signed content - a zip file (actually a jar file, which is basically a zip file).

We are then referenced to the exact jar file which triggered the failure, and are then told that the reason the jar could not be opened is due to :
[ZipException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipException.html) - `zip END header not found`.

Reading up a little on this exception revealed the following:
Your jar file is probably corrupted, and the best practice in similiar cases called for deleting the corrupted jar file and trying to get a fresh copy of this file.

Additional advice is to make sure you are using up-to-date JDK/JREs, since the zip support libraries are part of the Java core libraries, and a mismatch between versions could cause a failure in the recognition of the Zip file format as a legal format. This has also been suggested by [Arun Subramanian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5770084/arun-subramanian) in the comments to this questions.

In this case, I would suggest trying to get a different Eclipse installation file, since the installer you downloaded might contain a faulty jar.

Refernces:

- [Invalid end header bad central directory size zipexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366254/invalid-end-header-bad-central-directory-size-zipexception)
- [Why my application failed to deploy with-error jav/](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/334034/why-my-application-failed-to-deploy-with-error-jav/)
- [java.util.zip.ZipException](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2054020)