# How to fix Maven invalid end header

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've set up a default Maven project in Eclipse but when I run `mvn clean test` or run Maven test from Eclipse, I get a set of errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project gsn-editor: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
>   [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\owner.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-project\2.2.1\maven-project-2.2.1.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/owner/git/repository/gsn-editor/gsn-editor/src/model/package-info.java:[25,1] cannot access model
>   [ERROR]   invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/owner/git/repository/gsn-editor/gsn-editor/src/model/base/package-info.java:[27,1] cannot access model.base
>   [ERROR]   invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/owner/git/repository/gsn-editor/gsn-editor/src/test/TestSacmElement.java:[1,1] cannot access test
>   [ERROR]   invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
>   [ERROR] /C:/Users/owner/git/repository/gsn-editor/gsn-editor/src/model/base/SacmElement.java:[3,8] cannot access java
>   [ERROR]   invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

What does that all mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Strange.. Can you simply try deleting the directory located at `~/.m2`, then try a rebuild? This will cause _all_ artifacts to be re-downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Your jar files are corrupted. As was said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366254/invalid-end-header-bad-central-directory-size-zipexception) post, you can try to figure out which jars are corrupted and delete this jars from `.m2` directory, or remove all content of `.m2/repository` directory if there are a lot of them and then rebuild your application with maven.

Comment: Didn't change a thing for me !