# Adding JSTL dependies leads to maven issue and not displaying the pages through controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jstl, pom.xml, maven-dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven issue occurs after adding this

```
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\jstl\jstl\1.2\jstl1.2.jar;
 invalid END header (bad central directory offset)

[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.12.3\ecj-3.12.3.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\jstl\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar; invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
```

After adding above dependencies maven error occurs in spring boot project, controller is also not displays the page after adding this jstl dependencies.  But I want jstl dependencies for display the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that these jstl jar files are corrupted in your local maven repository. As was said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366254/invalid-end-header-bad-central-directory-size-zipexception) post, you can delete this jars from `.m2` directory, or remove all content of `.m2/repository` directory and then rebuild your project.